# Elasticsearch + сообщения из ВК

Tags: вконтакте, elasticsearch

Написал воркер, который при запуске собирает все диалоги из ВК и кладет их в `elasticsearch`.

Также он в реальном времени собирает все сообщения и кладет в все тот же `elastic`.

Следовательно, нужно предусмотреть ту ситуацию, когда у нас упал сервер или упал воркер и сбор данных не ведется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При следующем старте нужно каким-то образом обновлять базу данных.

Встает вопрос - как лучше это делать?

У меня в голове только один реальный метод: это перед каждым добавлением очередного сообщения проверять есть ли ID сообщения в базе, но это сильно замедлит работу, что недопустимо.

Слаб в эластике.

Comment: Try/catch вот, советую так

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer, разве мы не можем сохранить два полностью идентичных документа?)

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer особенно если сервак упал)) точно поможет Try/catch

Comment: Либо сохраняйте id сообщений, к примеру, в какой-то файл, либо с эластика в первую очередь берите все id, а потом при записи смотрите есть ли там он

Comment: @InDevX, мда. Решение конечно, но в целом логично. Наверное так и сделаю

Comment: Если в api есть какой-то offset и записи отдаются упорядочено то это по-другому решить можно, а так вариантов не много.. Попробуйте на англоязычном стаке вопрос создать

Comment: @InDevX, после того, как я сказал не слишком хорошую вещь про PHP - меня там забанили и не любят